# NTLM авторизация js

Tags: javascript, auth, ntlm

Столкнулся с windows авторизацией на сервере. Необходимо отправить заголовки для авторизации. Пробовал различные способы и через authenticate и классические способы..везде указывал тип ntlm но каждый раз выбрасывается со стороны сервера сообщение , что авторизация не пройдена.. С постмана условного если оправлять данные то все окей происходит. Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобной проблемой ? Сколько не гуглил , толковых решений не нашел для этой темы. Заранее спасибо

```
headers: [
            {
                'accept': 'application/json',
                'content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                'authorization': 'NTLM rafdjhdahfdkisfh3r8218341hfdkjs='
            }
```

ну и наверное важным уточнением будет , что запрос делается через протокол odata

Comment: По идее низким уровнем обработки занимается **браузер**. Во первых NTLM авторизация двухфазная. Т.е. после первого запроса, надо разпарсить ответ, и на его базе сгенерировать ещё один запрос. Во вторых... ну лично я не нашёл библиотеки корректно работающие с ntlm на низком уровне, про JS уже молчу. Это тонны кода, шифрования и т п. Если по каким-то причинам браузер не понял что хосту нужна NTLM авторизация - то сделайте ссылку на однопиксельную картинку, iframe или какой-то другой способ обращения к хосту используя старый способ. Если авторизация не происходит автоматически - это баг браузера.

Comment: Ещё раз, 1. NTML авторизацию делает браузер без участия JS. 2. Заголовки шифрования браузер возможно отсекает, возможно нет. Мне не удалось повторить шифрование NTML (пакет шифруется), а именно правильно посчитать хеш пароля. 3. Что бы авторизация прошла автоматически - поставьте image или iframe с ссылкой на хост. 4. Если вы хотите избавится от назойливой таблички - почитайте "сквозная авторизация" или "прозрачная авторизация".

Comment: NTLM шаг 1 - браузер шлёт "заголовок", c меткой NTLMSSP, у вас этой метки нету, т.к. ,`NTLM TlRMTVN` - вот такое начало должно быть. Шаг 2. Браузер получает ответ от сервера 401 + заголовок `WWW-Authenticate`, разворачивает base64 в байты, вычитывает ключи, шифрует их с паролем, заворачивает в NTLM3TYPE, пакует в base64, отправляет на сервер. Где-то так.

Comment: А что такое rafdjhdahfdkisf? Это `AD A7 DD 8E 17 5A 85 F7 64 8A C7 E1 DE BF 36 D7 CD F8 D6 17 DD 92 3B` п- росто какой-то набор байт который ниочём не говорит. Сервак на такое кажись 400 Bad request должен ответить. Тут должна быть NTLMSSP сигнатура, если речь о NTLM идёт. *С постмана условного* - нет так не подходит, или с постмана или с условного. Ваше "условное" - скорее всего программа с использованием хорошей HTTP библиотеки, которая NTLM реазизует "из коробки". Если клиент и сервер в домене - авторизация происходит у таких либ автоматически по-умолчанию.

Comment: @nick_n_a, может быть настала пора написать ответ на основе комментариев?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin 1. Я не вижу что автор сам понимает что делает 2. Это не решает проблему. Ответ будет просто висеть, ещё и заминусуют.  Поэтому пусть вопрос будет закрыт, автор увидит куда ему копать, дополнит вопрос информацией - тогда возможно на этот вопрос можно будет правильно ответить. А возможно, допускаю, изобрели какой-то новый NTLM и я не прав))))